# Svelte - access child component's method

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have an app that simply hides content `Hidden.svelte`:

```
<script>
    let shown = false;

    function show() {
        shown = true;
    }
</script>

<svelte:options accessors={true}/>

{#if shown}
    <slot/>
{/if}
```

Parent `App.svelte`:

```
<script>
    import Hidden from 'Hidden';

    let child;
</script>

<Hidden bind:this={child}>
    Content
</Hidden>

<button on:click={() => child.shown = true}>Show</button>
```

So, child's `shown` can be easily set due to `<svelte:options accessors={true}/>` in parent

But, I want to use method `show()` since it can not only set `shown` value, but also perform some magic

Thx to Chrome's DevTools, I found that all components have an `Array` with props and methods, that could be accessed via some `.$$.ctx`, so Hidden's `show()` method can be called like this:

```
<button on:click={() => child.$$.ctx[2]()}>Show</button>
```

But) You know) Is there is a legal way to do it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`Hidden.svelte`

```html
<script>
    let shown = false;

    export function show() {
        shown = true;
    }
</script>

{#if shown}
    <slot/>
{/if}
```

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import Hidden from './Hidden.svelte';

    let child;
</script>

<Hidden bind:this={child}>
    Content
</Hidden>

<button on:click={() => child.show()}>Show</button>
```

The call to `child.show()` can actually be simplified, but I thought this could make it harder to figure out what's going on in the example. You can do just:

```html
<button on:click={child.show}>Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution than binding the whole child component is to bind the child's component method in the parent :

`Hidden.svelte`

```html
<script>
    let shown = false;

    export function show() {
        shown = true;
    }
</script>

{#if shown}
    <slot/>
{/if}
```

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import Hidden from './Hidden.svelte';

    let childShow;
</script>

<Hidden bind:show={childShow}>
    Content
</Hidden>

<button on:click={() => childShow()}>Show</button>
```